# Google Groups Settings API without user auth?

Tags: google-groups-api, google-groups-settings

I have several hundred groups in my Google Apps for Business account.  I want to batch update a bunch of settings so I downloaded the PHP client.  I can't figure out how to provide the info to query and update the settings.  It seems like everything is designed around the concept of a user logging in with a web browser.  I registered the app at the API console under "Simple API Access" with "Key for server apps (with IP locking)".  I don't seem to be able to make any queries though, I get permission denied.

Example URL:
https://www.googleapis.com/groups/v1/groups/groupname@mydomain.com?key=MY_KEY_HERE'

Gives me:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<errors xmlns="http://schemas.google.com/g/2005">
 <error>
  <domain>GData</domain>
  <code>required</code>
  <location type="header">Authorization</location>
  <internalReason>Login Required</internalReason>
 </error>
</errors>
```

Is this supposed to be possible?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to perform OAuth 2.0 authentication as a Google Apps Super Admin to make Groups Settings API calls.

Rather than reinventing the wheel, you may just want to use [Dito GAM](http://ditoweb.com/dito-gam) to [update the group settings](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-manager/wiki/GroupSettingsExamples) in [bulk](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-manager/wiki/BulkOperations).